# Summation and integration, complex functions

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be any complex function and let $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n g_n(z)$ for some functions $g_n(z)$. Let $A$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and consider
$$I:=\int_A f(z)g(z)dx\ dy$$
where $z=x+iy$. Assume that I know that $\int_A |f(z)g(z)|dxdy$ converges and is finite. Hence (if I'm not wrong) I can apply Tonelli/Fubini's theorem to exchange sum and integral, so that
$$J:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\int_A f(z)g_n(z)dx\ dy$$
is actually equal to $I$.

Instead, assume now that the integral defining $I$ is convergent and finite, but both
$$\int_A |f(z)g(z)|dx\ dy=\infty\quad\quad\mbox{and}\quad\quad\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_A|c_n f(z)g(z)|dx\ dy=\infty$$
Is it still true that $J=I$? If not, what additional conditions would be necessary/sufficient?

Comment: How can you have one "$\int$" and $dx,dy$?  Shouldn't you need to integrals?

Comment: @SimpleArt $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, which can be seen as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence the $dx\ dy$

Answer (score 0):

No, to apply Fubini to interchange $\sum$ and $\int$, you need
$$
\int_A \;\sum_{n=0}^\infty |c_n| |f(z)g_n(z)|\;dx\ dy < \infty
$$

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know Fubini only gives a sufficient condition, not a necessary one. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is true.  The conclusion of Fubini might sometimes hold even if the hypothesis of Fubini fails.